# Overloading comparison operators in derived class right private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I've got two classes here. A Base class:

```
class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A(int n):x(n){}

    friend bool operator==(const A& left, const A& right)
    {return left.x==right.x;}
};
```

and a derived class that inherits from A privately:

```
class B : private A
{
    int y;
public:
    B(int n,int x):A(x),y(n){}
    friend bool operator==(const B& left, const B& right)
    {
        if(left.y==right.y)
        {/*do something here...*/}
        else{return false;}
    }
};
```

I know how to compare two instances of A: I just the member variables to each other. But how can I possibly compare instances of B? two instances could easily have different "x" members inside their associated "A" instances, but I have no idea how to compare those instances to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the instances to `A&` and use the equality operator for `class A`:

```
if (static_cast<A&>(left) == static_cast<A&>(right)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: welp, I assumed it was something simple like that!

Comment: You should cast to `A&` to avoid constructing temporary `A` objects.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Following this example, I get a compile time error.  Like the original code, I am passing in the derived class as an argument, but my compiler says that it cannot static_cast from the derived reference type to the base reference type.  No errors when I just static_cast to the object, though... although this does create the extra step of constructing a temporary object.